# R httr POST function return Send failure: Connection was reset

Tags: r, post, httr

I am trying to scrape the table under the Market Segment tab as in the below image, The code logic blow used to work with similar tasks, however it is not working here and returning

Error Send failure: Connection was reset

```
link<-'https://www.egx.com.eg/en/prices.aspx'
  headers.id <-c('User-Agent'= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36',
                 'Referer'= 'https://www.egx.com.eg/en/prices.aspx',
                 'Content-Type'= 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                 'Origin'='https://www.egx.com.eg',
                 'Host'= 'www.egx.com.eg',
                 'Content-Type'= 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                 'sec-ch-ua'='" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"'
                 )

  pgsession<-session(link,httr::add_headers(.headers=headers.id), verbose())

  pgform<-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]


  page<-POST(link, body=list(

    '__EVENTTARGET'= pgform$fields$`__EVENTTARGET`$value,
    '__EVENTARGUMENT'=pgform$fields$`__EVENTARGUMENT`$value,
    '__VIEWSTATE'=pgform$fields$`__VIEWSTATE`$value,
    'ctl00$H$txtSearchAll'=pgform$fields$`ctl00$H$txtSearchAll`$value,
    'ctl00$H$rblSearchType'=pgform$fields$`ctl00$H$rblSearchType`$value,
    'ctl00$H$rblSearchType'=pgform$fields$`ctl00$H$rblSearchType`$value,
    'ctl00$H$imgBtnSearch'=pgform$fields$`ctl00$H$imgBtnSearch`$value,
    'ctl00$C$S$TextBox1'=pgform$fields$`ctl00$C$S$TextBox1`$value
  ),
  encode="form", verbose()
  )
```

[image: Image showing the table I am tiring to scrape]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keeped seacrhing till i find the solution using rvest as follows:

```
  link<-'https://www.egx.com.eg/en/prices.aspx'
  headers.id <-c('Accept'='*/*',
                 'Accept-Encoding'='gzip, deflate, br',
                 'Accept-Language'='en-US,en;q=0.9',
                 'Cache-Control'='no-cache',
                 'Connection'='keep-alive',
                 'Content-Type'='application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                 'Host'='www.egx.com.eg',
                 'Origin'='https://www.egx.com.eg',
                 'Referer'='https://www.egx.com.eg/en/prices.aspx',
                 'sec-ch-ua'='" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
                 'sec-ch-ua-mobile'='?0',
                 'Sec-Fetch-Dest'='empty',
                 'Sec-Fetch-Mode'='cors',
                 'Sec-Fetch-Site'='same-origin',
                 'User-Agent'='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.59',
                 'X-MicrosoftAjax'='Delta=true'
  )
  
  pgsession<-session(link,httr::add_headers(.headers=headers.id))
  pgform<-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
  filled_form<-html_form_set(pgform,
                             '__EVENTTARGET'= 'ctl00$C$S$lkMarket',
                             '__EVENTARGUMENT'=pgform$fields$`__EVENTARGUMENT`$value,
                             '__VIEWSTATE'=pgform$fields$`__VIEWSTATE`$value,
                             'ctl00$H$txtSearchAll'=pgform$fields$`ctl00$H$txtSearchAll`$value,
                             'ctl00$H$rblSearchType'=pgform$fields$`ctl00$H$rblSearchType`$value,
                             'ctl00$H$rblSearchType'="1",
                             'ctl00$H$imgBtnSearch'=pgform$fields$`ctl00$H$imgBtnSearch`$value,
                             'ctl00$C$S$TextBox1'=pgform$fields$`ctl00$C$S$TextBox1`$value
  )
  page<-session_submit(pgsession,filled_form)
 
  # in the above example change eventtarget as "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DataList2$ctl02$lnk_blok" to get different table
  page.html <-read_html(page$response)%>%html_table%>%.[[7]]
```